# Detect values in array that are statistically inconsistent

Tags: statistics

I have a list of values:

```
1542 104 360 209 195 1 50
```

Applicable to the algorithm I am trying to write, 1542 should be thrown out of my series and therefore not considered in later processing.  This is because the preponderance of the place values of 4 of the numbers.  I keep 1 and 50 because these are not wildly out of range.

My value series may also have a much greater magnitude:

```
4087 5109 63 5799 4714 4377 8379
```

And in this case I would throw out 63.  The others fit into my "believable" category again as these are within the same place value.

The data is from an ultrasonic time measurement process.  Glitches do happen and these need to be thrown out or the end result data may spike unnecessarily.  It may be helpful to know that these values are sampled in less than 1 millisecond, and that what is being measured has no chance of changing so fast.

However I also run the problem that my values may twiddle between two place values:

```
100 99 102 49 30 1930 14
```

In this case the preponderance of place value goes to 99, 49, 39, and 14 but 100 and 102 is not that far away and should be included.  1930 is to be excluded.  There's not enough evidence that it's value by the fact this place value occurs only once.

Maybe this is addressed in statistics?

Is there an equation that can help me here, and/or a mathematics principle I can do more reading about which might help in fashioning a decent algorithm?

Comment: This is not a mathematical question nor does it have a definite answer. For instance, some processes have regular variation when the observations are expressed as *logarithms* (as is often the case in chemistry: pH is a log). In your first example the common logs all vary between 3.2 and 1.7, averaging around 2. However, one of them is zero: it's far below all the rest. That would make $1$ the outlier, not $1542$. A good answer to this question will therefore consider the nature of the process, its statistical characteristics, and the objectives of the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is addressed in statistics. It lies in the research field which can be called "robust statistics" for estimation, or detection or some further signal processing tasks. There is a vast literature contributed by both mathematicians as well as engineers. The contaminating data which you encountered in your application are called outliers. They dont follow your statistical model. How to attenuate or remove them is not easy in general because you will always have the risk to remove useful data as well. I dont know your mathematical background but you can check this one: http://www.shiae.cuhk.edu.hk/seminar/Zoubir%20DL%20robust%20statistics%202011.pdf

Comment: Thanks.  A bit out of my league, but a little reading so far indicates a track to follow.  Have to keep simple as small system with low power/memory to support.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't do this with statistics, but rather with some type of filtering. As you mention in your question, it doesn't make sense if there is a large sudden jump in the value you measure.

**Option 1:**
If you're looking for a quick fix, my suggestion would be to pick a reasonable threshold, either relative (e.g. 1%) or absolute (e.g. 200) and reject all values in your measurement series that change by more than this threshold when compared to the previous measurement.

**Option 2:**
This will take a bit more effort, but you can take a (discrete) Fourier transform of your measurement series and apply a [low-pass filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter) to your data. This will remove all the high frequency noise from your dataset, while maintaining the low frequency measurement data.

Comment: I like Option 1.  Can't do threshold as magnitudes are wide, but maybe percent deviation from one to next value?  Or maybe first sort and check deviation from lowest to highest value?

Comment: Option 1 is statistically terrible, for many reasons, and option 2 requires strong assumptions to be valid. Consult the [stats site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/outliers?sort=votes&pagesize=15) for better solutions and discussion.

Comment: For the general case, I agree with you, but I think, given the explanation of the OP, these options are both not necessarily statistically terrible. He mentions himself: "Glitches do happen and these need to be thrown out or the end result data may spike unnecessarily. It may be helpful to know that these values are sampled in less than 1 millisecond, and that what is being measured has no chance of changing so fast." So we are not looking at the tails of a normal distribution, we are really looking at spikes in the data which are easily recognized by thresholding

Comment: Moreover, from the sentence "these values are sampled in less than 1 millisecond, and that what is being measured has no chance of changing so fast", I would think that using a low-pass filter doesn't need any additional assumptions

Comment: Thresholding is a good thought.  Question is how to set it when there is the potential of dynamics (not within the fast samples (milliseconds), but over time measured in seconds).

Comment: That's a good point. I guess you have to know quite a bit about the physics/chemistry of what you're measuring to be able to set a sensible absolute or relative threshold.